# Windows.UI.Xaml namespace is not been supported in visual studio 2012 for windows phone development

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use the namespace Windows.UI.Xaml; in visual studio 2012 for windows app development and it is not been supported. It is giving the error that Windows.UI does not contain Xaml but i have seen in sample code which i have downloaded from here

http://www.mediafire.com/download/d1yva79g1ml35vq/FacebookSample.rar

They are using the namespace Windows.UI.Xaml and no error is there.
Can anyone help me out to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at the code you provided but I assume it is not Windows Phone code. Windows.UI.Xaml is indeed not available for Windows Phone. It's not mentionend as a supported platform on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.aspx) anyway.

In [Sharing XAML UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714088%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you can read more about the difference between Windows 8 UI controls and Windows Phone 8 UI controls. Bottom line: XAML on both platforms are not binary compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You are refering to the Windows 8 Store Application,

Windows.UI.Xaml.dll is a type of DLL file comes with Windows 8.

Read this article on converting Windows Phone to Windows store and corresponding namespaces.

[Converting to Windows 8 from Windows Phone](http://www.jayway.com/2012/04/10/converting-to-windows-8-from-windows-phone-xaml-has-a-new-home-4-of-12/)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that you gave is a **Windows Store** app sample. And that's the reason you are seeing `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace. If you would make a Windows Phone solution, you won't find this .dll file or namespace.

The only practical thing related to `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace which is seen in the sample code which would interoperate to Windows Phone is Visibility of XAML components. While you have `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace in Windows Store apps, you have complementary `System.Windows` namespace in Windows Phone for toggling Visibility.